# Server.MapPath - Not allowed to load local resource error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, io

I use `Server.MapPath` to access some images on server. And I got the right path but can't open it.
The error I got is:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: d:/Project/MyProject/WebUI/Uploads/User_18234/leopard.jpg
```

I suppose that this will work on server. But I need it on localhost to test. Is there any solution for this?

```
...
userId = GetUserId();
string path = Server.MapPath("Uploads/User_" + userId + "/");
model.Name = path + model.Name + "_Original." + model.Extension;
...
```

Comment: See if the account under which the website is running has the permissions to access the directory of the images.

Comment: Are you providing relative path or absolute path for the images?

Comment: I have only imageName and UserId. Based on that I wan't to build relative path. I updated question with code.

Comment: Sounds like a permissons issue. Have you tried on yourlive server and see if it works there?

Comment: No. I don't have live server now. But I'am trying to fix this on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/User_" + userId + "/");
```

Map path need Virtual path so "~/" will surely fix it.

Comment: No it doesn't work like that. But it works when I use "../../../../Uploads/User...".

Comment: yes you are correct, it means the virtual path you need is "~/../../../Uploads/User...". Path must be with respect to project root.

Comment: This means that when I write "~/../../../Something" this actually is relative path. Am I right?

Comment: if possible do use the Absolute path e.g. "~/<dir>/<dir>/<file>" better approach than the relative path e.g "../../<file>". Reason is that "../" varies w.r.t caller(page) depth

Answer (score 2):

For me removing Server.MapPath worked.. I use tild ('~') sign with the url and it worked perfectly.

```
string path = "~/Uploads/User_" + userId + "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 string url ="E:\braja" ;                    
 var path = Path.Combine(@"" + url + "","_" + fileName);
```

it work for me